# How to replace in file SQL specific lines?

Tags: awk, sed

I tried some sed & awk prior to asking with no success so here I am.

What I am looking to do it to replace some lines in place (in .sql file) in bash script. The problem is as I see it with SQL specific backticks & possibly with single quotes?

Actual thing to do is to replace lines like

```sql
`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '-1',
```

to

```sql
`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
```

SQL dump is ~10 Gb.

```perl
sed -i 's/`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '-1',/`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,/' file.sql
```

or using the line number:

```perl
sed -i '357s/.*/`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,/' file.sql
```

```
awk 'NR==357 {$0="`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,"} 1' file.sql
```

Also forgot to mention that using backslashes on escape characters did not help.

Comment: Your first `sed` attempt would fail because you can't nest single quotes. The other two look to me like they should have worked. Please try to provide a [mre].

Comment: It's just the "DEFAULT '-1'" part that you want to remove from the payment_methods column? Or anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==357{sub(/ DEFAULT \047-1\047,/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

OR in case you want to verify contents of 357th line too along with its line number then try following.

```
awk '
FNR==357 && /`payment_methods` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT \047-1\047,/{
  sub(/ DEFAULT \047-1\047,/,"")
}
1' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** This will print the lines on terminal, once you are happy with results then you could append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above solution to save output into Input_file itself.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to test your code without printing out all lines in file?

Comment: @YevhenOrestov, sure try like `awk 'FNR==357{sub(/ DEFAULT \047-1\047,/,"");print}' Input_file` and this will print only that specific line, apply same to my OR solution too, let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```perl
sed -rn "357s/(^.*payment_methods.*text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)( DEFAULT.*-1.*)(,$)/\1\3/p" file
```

Split line 357 into 3 sections based on regular expressions and then substitute the line for the first and the third sections, printing the result.

To commit the changes back to the file, add -i and so:

```perl
sed -ri "357s/(^.*payment_methods.*text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)( DEFAULT.*-1.*)(,$)/\1\3/" file
```